# How to change the order of three divs in two columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three divs which I want to order differently from the way they appear on the markup.

I want to show div **one** first, and then **three** below it on the first column. And then on the second column, I want to show only div **two**.
My current CSS setup can't achieve it. How can I move div **two** into the second column?

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box>* {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.box>div:first-child{
    flex: 1 1 70%;
    width: 70% !important;
}

.box>div:nth-child(2) {
    flex: 1 1 30%;
    order: 3;
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}

.box>div:nth-child(3) {
    flex: 1 1 70%;
    width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `width`s are defined in the CSS,
maybe not using `flex` system is easier here:

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.box > * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 70%;
}

.box>div:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do this with dynamic height.  Unfortunately, there's no way for the browser to determine when or where it should wrap the second child to the next column if you do that.  It all fits in one column because you haven't really told it how tall the flex container should be.  Adding a height and swapping the flex declarations for `flex: 1 1 auto` and `flex: 1 1 100%` creates the wrapping to a second column that you seem to be trying to achieve.

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
}
.box {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  /* without this, it doesn't wrap to
     a second column.  You can change
     this to whatever height best fits
     your requirements. */
  height: 100px;
}
.box>* {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 70%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.box>div:nth-child(2) {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="box">
    <div>One</div>
    <div>Two
      <p>paragraph</p>
    </div>
    <div>Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have done that using a table method you can do that by using grid layout also but I used table tags because grid css may arise a problem in Internet explorer because IE doesnot support grid css.

```css
.main {
      width: 400px;
    }
    .box {
      width: 50%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .box td {
        flex: 1 1 100%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="main">
      <div class="box">
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td rowspan=2>Two
          <p>paragraph</p>
        </td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This may achieve the layout, but it does require a total rewrite of the HTML, and HTML tables should typically be reserved for when you have tabular content.